# PHPUnit with Symfony Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle' not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm trying to testing my app made with Symfony. I wrote a test and when I launch it, i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle' 
>   not found in /.../app/AppKernel.php on line 17

I had the same error with Symfony's `MonologBundle`, `AsseticBundle` and `SwiftmailerBundle`: then I've manually added these bundles into my app, so pheraps I have fixed those errors, but with Doctrine I've not found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe you did not install the Doctrine bundle.
Try to go to the root of your project where the composer.phar is located through a console, and try to run it like this:

```
php composer.phar
```

It will install all dependencies of Symfony2,and hopefully everything is going to work :)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I've probably made some mistakes updating my dependencies with composer in the past.